# Работа с facebook api

Tags: android, java, json, facebook-api

> Дело вот в чем, я пытаюсь по
> выбранному человеку вывести картинку,
> его аватарку, нашел в интернете полным
> полно примеров но ни один не
> отображает картинку, по идее нужно
> кешировать картинку на устройстве.
> Может кто нибудь работал с этим апи и
> может мне рассказать - может есть в
> этом апи какие нибудь  элементы
> которые отображают с ссылки фотографии
> или например что нибудь другое. Так
> как фото приходит в формате json его
> нужно парсить, то не проблема ссылку
> достал, а вот как дальше его
> отобразить в имейджВью или в другой
> вьюхе я без понятия, у кого нибудь
> есть идеи?

**UPDATE:**
Послушал я Романа, попробовал использовать либу которая находится по его ссылке, но у меня при использовании появляется масса ошибок.

```
    02-28 18:55:21.567: E/AndroidRuntime(10067): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 18:55:21.567: E/AndroidRuntime(10067): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader
02-28 18:55:21.567: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at com.example.testproject.FriendOpenProfile.<init>(FriendOpenProfile.java:32)
02-28 18:55:21.567: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-28 18:55:21.567: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
02-28 18:55:21.567: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
02-28 18:55:21.567: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
02-28 18:55:21.567: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-28 18:55:21.567: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-28 18:55:21.567: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-28 18:55:21.567: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 18:55:21.567: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 18:55:21.567: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-28 18:55:21.567: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 18:55:21.567: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-28 18:55:21.567: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-28 18:55:21.567: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-28 18:55:21.567: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Я так подозреваю что с фейсбук апи оно не работает, так как если проект без феййсбук апи то все скачивается нормально и показывается. Может кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот ответ на все твои вопросы](http://nostra13android.blogspot.ru/2012/03/4-universal-image-loader-part-1.html)

Comment: Я там уже был, сильно громоздкая библиотека, я думал что-то проще найти...

Comment: ну тогда единственный вариант - собственный велосипед.
хотя библиотека классная

Comment: та не поспоришь либа что нужно но блин она тяжеленная... тем более для вывода одной фотки она кажись не канает

Comment: Конфликтует с фейсбук апи, как подключаю его не импортируется, когда импортирую принудительно - build path то выдает ошибку пр искачке, не сталкивались?

Answer (score 0):

в php я делал так:

```
//После валидации
    $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
       . $_SESSION['fb_token'];
    $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
//если айди пользователя известна то можно так
    $avatar = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user->id.'/picture';

echo '<img src="'.$avatar.'"/>';
```

Comment: та что мне пхп) в пхп можно отобразить просто так ссылку, а в дроиде её нужно сперва стянуть на телефон, а потом токо вывести